# What is this over?

Tags: phrase-meaning, zero-article, singular-vs-plural

"I walked over hill and valley" from a workbook

Does this mean walk all over hill and valley?
or other things?

Comment: It's funny, the words you italicized seem straightforward to me, and the ones you didn't, don't.

Comment: @DanBron - I guess the main question is in the headline: "what is this **over**?"

Answer (score 6):

The preposition "over" has been used in the sense of across, throughout, or from one side to the other side of the hill and the valley.

Comment: Is it just me, or should hill and valley be taken to be (possibly) plural?  I read "over hill and valley" as a kind of summary, where it could be translated to "over at least one hill and at least one valley".

Comment: I think "over hill and valley" is idiomatic and metaphorical here.  It does not mean literally one hill and one valley, just a way of describing terrain.

Comment: A similar idiom is "over hill and dale" which just means traveling through varying terrain, often walking.

Comment: I agree with @colllin, this is just a fancy/poetic way to say over hill[s] and valley[s]. It doesn't (and can't) mean one specific hill or valley. Colllin's 'translation' is right. (And I think the OP's real confusion is coming from the lack of any article for hill and valley, but I might be wrong.)

Comment: I don't see across here....It seems to me to mean "I walked all over hills and valleys..." like "there's paper all over the floor." Am I totally wrong on this? Is  my interpretation a possibility?

Comment: 8906335678, Across also means from one side to the other of something. He walked across the road.

Comment: @8906335678 - "Over" just means "[across a barrier or intervening space](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over)".  It does not mean the same thing as "all over", so no, a native speaker would not interpret it that way.

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/across

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/across